# EXEC_BAD_ACCESS signal received in an iphone application

Tags: ios4

In my iphone application i am getting an error 'EXEC_BAD_ACCESS'.First time when i run application it ran and at some point of time i got this error and the application terminated.After that i am not able to run it.
The error occurred at main.m in second line of code.

Comment: Try clearing the project and deleting the app from iPhone simulator. And see if you can run the app at least once again.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you're not overreleasing something or that you are not calling on an object you have not allocate for, if you post a small code snippet we can possibly help you some more.

Comment: But how can i figure out which object is causing the error?I am getting the error from here:-
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
    [pool release];
    return retVal;
}

Comment: I recommend running instruments to check for Zombies this will tell you what object you're trying to use that has been released